# Magento 2 Rest API return multiple interface class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api

On the Magento 2, I want to custom return object on my custom rest API, I have code like this on the Hz\Clients\Api\TransactionInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Hz\Clients\Api;

interface TransactionInterface 
{

    /**
     * Get List Data by Client Id
     *
     * @param string $clientId
     * 
     * @return \Hz\Clients\Api\Data\FirstOptionDataInterface|\Hz\Clients\Api\Data\SecondOptionDataInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     */
    public function getTransaction($clientId);
}
```

here is my `FirstOptionDataInterface.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Hz\Clients\Api\Data;

interface FirstOptionDataInterface 
{
    const INFO_MESSAGE = "info_message";

    /**
     * @param mixed $infoMessage
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInfoMessage($infoMessage);

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInfoMessage();

}
```

and this is for `SecondOptionDataInterface.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Hz\Clients\Api\Data;

interface SecondOptionDataInterface 
{
    const TRANSACTIONS = "transactions";

    /**
     * @param mixed $transactions
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTransactions($transactions);

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTransactions();

}
```

so when on the rest API method I select the first option then it will return `\Hz\Clients\Api\Data\FirstOptionDataInterface` object and if I select the second option then it will return `\Hz\Clients\Api\Data\SecondOptionDataInterface`, is it possible to do that in rest API Magento 2?

> note: I cannot use throw exception for it since the format of throw
>   exception output is different from my requirement.

Comment: you shouldn't do this. is it possible for you to create a "parent-interface"? or are both interfaces too different?

Comment: hi @PhilippSander, yes both interface is too different that why I must separate them, for "parent-interface" could you give me an example ? I'm sorry my oop still bad.

Comment: why don't you inject it to the constructor?

Comment: then the question: why can you return both? sounds like it should be split in 2 endpoints. can you provide us both interfaces?

Comment: hi @PhilippSander okay I already edit my question, actually I want to integrate with other system and they ask me for provide 2 different format outputs when hits the endpoint url. do you think is possible to be like this on magento 2 ?

Comment: hi @NID, I did it, but it always return first interface ignore the condition which I set on the code.

Comment: sounds like a software-design flaw for me.... how do you deceide which response you are sending